# Force homebrew to completely reinstall wireshark

Tags: wireshark, homebrew

I've messed up trying to install wireshark on OSX. Here's what I did.

- I downloaded and installed wireshark from their website. It didn't work due to missing X11.
- I started to troubleshoot this, but found there was a homebrew recipe (surprise!)
- I uninstalled wireshark according to their detailed delete-this-delete-that instructions included in the dmg.
- I installed the homebrew recipe. When I ran homebrew it complained of WIRESHARK_APP_DIR not being set. A quick google showed that this was a conflict between versions of /usr/local/bin/wireshark
- I (stupidly?) did a `rm /usr/local/bin/wireshark` and attempted a re-install with brew.
- I brew reinstalled, relinked, forced, updated and all manner of commands trying to get a `wireshark` command back, but without any luck.

With every wireshark installation completely uninstalled, I am still unable to get a successful install of wireshark via brew, due to this missing binary. What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

My error was assuming there was anything wrong with my wireshark install. The default brew recipe for wireshark does not have the wireshark executable.

The following process enabled wireshark for me:

1. Manually install the dependency [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)
2. Execute `brew install -vd --build-from-source --with-gtk+3 --with-libpcap wireshark`

Then to run it, more tomfoolery:

1. Start xquartz.app

   1. open a terminal (command N)
   2. enter `host +` to allow connections to xquartz
   3. enter `echo $DISPLAY` to get the display ID
2. In iTerm, load d-bus. `launchctl load /usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.8.12/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist` (replace with appropriate version).
3. set the DISPLAY with the value from step 1.3 above. Assuming it was `:0` then `export DISPLAY=:0`
4. finally, run this sucker: `wireshark`

After all this the app will be running, but you won't be able to capture. That's my next challenge...

Comment: Not sure why exactly you need wireshark on MacOS, however tcpdump is readily available on MacOS and still works fine for 99% of most tasks I've seen people perform. If you need a libpcap-interpreting GUI on MacOS, then you might want to look at [Cocoa Packet Analyzer] (http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/index.php). And if you really need some fancy networking analysis features, get a copy of live KALI distribution and fire it up each time you need to perform some advanced network analysis. You'll save yourself a tremendous amount of time.